# itext variable issue

Tags: java

I am trying to show a variable value from class 'dbproperties' in the pdf document. Following code illustrates it,

```
dbproperties db = new dbproperties();

Chunk text1 = new Chunk(db.index_number);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.add(text1);
document.close();
```

but getting an error

> non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static content" for "Chunk text1 = new Chunk(db.index_number);

Can anyone help me with this please??

Comment: ok.can you add full source code?. at least add part of code problem occur

Comment: @raam030 you should post the *required* information in your question; e.g. in the situation at hand you have trouble with static or non-static members or code but the code you give us hides completely whether or not it is static or not.

Comment: public class dbproperties extends javax.swing.JFrame { String index_number; Some methods..... }

Comment: Please add the relevant code. We want to see where db is declared and dbproperties class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another attempt at guessing due to incomplete code:

Could it be that `db` is a non-static member of your class but the code is executed in some static method or code-block? E.g.

```
class YourClass
{
    dbproperties db = new dbproperties();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        [...]
        Chunk text1 = new Chunk(db.index_number);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.add(text1);
        document.close();
        [...]
    }
}
```

In this case the code cannot access `db` as the code is in a static method (i.e. not in the context of a single instance of your class) while the member to access is associated to a single instance.

In this case you need an instance of your class, e.g.

```
        [...]
        YourClass instance = new YourClass();
        Chunk text1 = new Chunk(instance.db.index_number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us more the precise code that causes this error?

My take is that you declared db variable separately, in non-static method or just as instance field:

```
dbproperties db = new dbproperties();
```

but the following code executed in statis method, like that:

```
public static void main(String[] argv){
   Chunk text1 = new Chunk(db.index_number);
   ....
}
```

Then **db** can not be accessed from main. They should be either both static or instance.
You can declare **db** inside main to solve it.

Comment: yes, got it fixed now .. You'r correct, I should have declared inside the main method / method in which I am trying to implement this. Thank you for the help..